# AttributeError: module 'dash.dash' has no attribute 'dependencies'

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

Below is my error,

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "app.py", line 54, in
>   
>       dash.dependencies.Output('react-graph','figure'), AttributeError: module 'dash.dash' has no attribute 'dependencies'

Below are my imports,

```
from dash import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import psycopg2
import os
import flask
```

Below is my callback function

```
@app.callback( dash.dependencies.Output('react-graph','figure'), [dash.dependencies.Input('reg_col','value')] )
```

I do not have any file named dash.py in my current directory. I have also tried to change to the import dash from dash to just import dash. The former gives me the below error.

> Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named 'dash.py' in your current directory.

below are the contents of my sys.path,

```
'P:\\CC\\Commercial\\Nilay\\ProjectX\\Interactivity_test\\Interactivity_test',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Babel-2.5.0-py3.6.egg',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\nilay.doshi\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

Comment: Why not just do: `@app.callback(Output('react-graph','figure'), [Input('reg_col','value')] `?

Comment: I pulled that off through the dash documentation https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2 regardless still gives the errors but it seems to execute with the from dash import dash. Still quite confusing why it wont work with the dash.dependencies included in the callback.

Comment: What is the purpose of `from dash import dash`? Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: Im really not sure I picked it up from some other code. But, if I just keep it as import dash and still carry out your correction from the first comment, I still get the error 'Dash was not successfully imported. Make sure you don't have a file named
'dash.py' in your current directory.'

Comment: There must be another module named `dash.py` somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH` (i.e. not necessarily in the current directory). What uis the output of `python -c 'import dash; print("dash.__file__")'`?

Comment: it just prints ' dash.__file__ ' . btw, I realised why using dash.dependencies is redundant when you actually already import it globally. Still perplexed about this dash.py issue

Comment: @ekhumoro I have added my sys.path contents to the question. I believe thats what you are looking for.

Comment: There's a typo in @ekhumoro 's comment. To find out the file from which 'dash' was imported, do `import dash ; print(dash.__file__)` (without quotes).

Comment: @moksha. As Leo K says, there's a typo in my comment. You need to get the specific path of the *dash.py* that is actually being imported.

Comment: The output is as follows - C:\Users\nilay.doshi\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site                                                                                   -packages\dash\__init__.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probing further, on checking the contents of the

```
__init__.py
```

file showed some incomplete lines in it probably missed out due to a bad installation.

I have altered the file with the contents from ([https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/dash/**init**.py](https://github.com/plotly/dash/blob/master/dash/__init__.py)) and the error is no more.